# If $f(n)=\omega(h(n))$ and $g(n)=o(h(n))$ then is $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

My question is exactly what the title says. If I have that $f(n)=\omega(h(n))$ and $g(n)=o(h(n))$ hold, then does $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ hold as well? My intuition says that the second part is false, but I couldn't put this idea on paper.

Comment: Consider the case $f = g$. Can a function be both $\omega(h(n))$ and $o(h(n))$? What can you deduce in the more general case?

Comment: $f(n) = n\log n, g(n) = \log n, h(n)=n$

Comment: Do you mean $\omega$ or $\Omega$?